# How to connect to stm32f205 via jtag or swd for read/write?

Tags: stm32, jtag, swd, mcu

Good day everyone.

There is a need to connect via jtag / swd to stm32f205.

There is a chip soldered by all pins.

[image: stm32f205 pinout]

There is a Chinese st-link v2

[image: st-link v2 from china]

I guess I need rst, swclk, swdio 3.3vdd

in datasheet it is 7, 49, 46, 48 pins

I'm not sure if I connected correctly and stm utility also does not see the chip.

I ask you to guide me on the right path and explain where I went wrong and how to do it right.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You didn't forget GND connection, right?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your forgot to install the STLink driver on your host machine.The pins you connected are OK as there is no need to connect the Gnd using this USB-STLink module.
For Linux Hosts you can find the packge in official repositories (use aptitude).
Further installation guildelines could be found [here](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link004.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your pins are ok (I hope you have not forgotten to connect the GND pin, since you have not mentioned it).
Let me remind you to choose SWD program mode in your programmer rather than JTAG.